How to return an object of a type depending on a parameter?
Consider the following function:
public IVehicleProcessor GetVehicle(VehicleType vehicleType, string regNo) {

    if (vehicleType == VehicleType.Car)
        return new CarProcessor(regNo);

    if (vehicleType == VehicleType.Van)
        return new VanProcessor(regNo);

    if (vehicleType == VehicleType.Truck)
        return new TruckProcessor(regNo);

    // the list goes on.

    return null;
}

And then in another ("child") project
public enum VehicleType {
    Car,
    Van,
    Truck,
    // etc.
}

Is there a way of re-writing this method so that it doesn't rely on a bunch of if statements? (And I don't mean by just changing it to a switch). This code will be customised a bit, and let's say I wanted to add, say, a Bus, I'd like to be able to just create a BusProcessor : IVehicleProcessor and add Bus to the VehicleType enum and GetVehicle() would just know what to do. Perhaps using Reflection or something?
For example, I was thinking maybe having the VehicleType as a property in IVehicleProcessor such that each 'processor' class would return its own Vehicle type, but I don't know how I could access that from GetVehicle() - especially as it would have to be done before it's instantiated. Could also make it a static property, but then how to enforce that using the IVehicleProcessor interface?

I'd go with a string instead of an enum and just provide the class'  name. That way you don't need to change anything when you add a new class. You can simlify this using some sort of convention, so that clients don't need to know the exact class-name (e.g. CarProcessor), but instead just Car, and your factory adds Processor.

You should probably get rid of the enumeration altogether and write a genetic method. The return type would be T and you'd constrain that to be your interface type. You would have to set the registration number as a property though, because you can only use a parameterless constructor on a generic type parameter. I'm on a phone so can't write code right now.

@jmcilhinney - thanks, but with a generic method, wouldn't the calling code have to know the "processor" type in advance of calling the method? Whereas what I need is for the method to figure out the type.

yeap. In particular generics won't help you with runtime-types.

While you can use reflection, I would recommend against it. Since it may easily result in runtime errors. While ifs or a switch is not immune to runtime errors, it can protect against some problems, and the code tend to be much more readable.

What kind of dependency injection do you use?

@TimSchmelter - using Autofac

Yes, the calling code would have to know the type, but that's also the case if you're using an enumeration if the value is hard coded. You haven't indicated where that argument would come from, so the question is not fully formed.

@jmcilhinney - the enumeration value will not be hard-coded - the idea is it should work no matter where the argument comes from, that the value is enough... isn't this what OOP is all about?

You could create a static factory class and let the concrete implementations register themselves in a static constructor:
public static class VehicleFactory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<IVehicleProcessor>> _processorFactory = [];

    public static void Register<T>() where T : IVehicleProcessor, new()
        => Register(typeof(T).Name, () => new T());

    public static void Register(string name, Func<IVehicleProcessor> create)
        => _processorFactory.Add(name, create);

    public static IVehicleProcessor CreateProcessor(string name)
        => _processorFactory[name]();
}

Example of a self-registering implementation:
public class TruckProcessor : IVehicleProcessor
{
    static TruckProcessor()
        => VehicleFactory.Register<TruckProcessor>();
}

Note that the static constructor is called before the first instance is created or any static members declared in that class (not its base classes) are referenced. Therefore, you may have to use one of the methods below (forcing or ModuleInitializer) to ensure its exceution:
See also:

Static Constructors (C# Programming Guide).
Forcing a static constructor to be called.
ModuleInitializer attribute.


One option is to use a dictionary with factory methods to create the objects you need. For example:
The dictionary with methods for each type:
private Dictionary<VehicleType, Func<string, IVehicleProcessor>> _processorFactory
    = new Dictionary<VehicleType, System.Func<string, IVehicleProcessor>>()
    {
        { VehicleType.Car, (string regNum) => new CarProcessor(regNum) }
        { VehicleType.Van, (string regNum) => new VanProcessor(regNum) }
        { VehicleType.Truck, (string regNum) => new TruckProcessor(regNum) }
    };

And to get a processor:
public IVehicleProcessor GetVehicle(VehicleType vehicleType, string regNo)
{
    if(!_processorFactory.TryGetValue(vehicleType, out var factoryMethod))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Don't know what to do for that vehicle type");
    }
    
    return factoryMethod(regNo);
}

However, this doesn't always work so well with dependency injection. So instead you may want to register the types in DI and instead of passing the regNo in the constructor, make it a property, you can create the type in a slightly safer way.

IMHO that's just another if/switch-approach.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain The point of all these patterns is to make sure there's only one switch. The main danger people try to avoid is having two switches that have to be kept in sync. Reworking the code to have zero switches may be impractical, depending on the context.

@Abstraction And the OP accomplished that in their question by having a method that every place that needs to map the enum into the value calls, so that only that one place needs to be updated with changes.  So in either solution there's still only one place to update.  The only "advantage" of this solution is that you can add/remove values to the collection at runtime rather than having the mapping be determined statically at compile time.

@Servy how would you do that at tunrime? The dictionary is pretty statically typed, or did I get yu whrong?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Well in theory you could do anything.  That's the point, it's a collection, rather than being harded coded.  In this specific answer, even though it's a collection it's still just hard coded and not modified, so it's no different than the code in the question.  It could theoretically be made to be different, but it isn't.  As for how you could actually populate it at runtime, the question itself specifies one approach, use reflection to search for the interfaces and populate the dictionary accordingly.

There is a way to refactor the code to have solution compliant with the Open Closed Principle using only .NET standard dependency injection.
public interface IVehicleProcessorFactory {
   bool Supports(VehicleType vehicleType);
   IVehicleProcessor Create(String regNo);
}

public class CarProcessorFactory : IVehicleProcessorFactory {
   bool Supports(VehicleType vehicleType) => vehicleType == VehicleType.Car;
   IVehicleProcessor Create(String regNo) => new CarProcessor(regNo);
}

public class VanProcessorFactory : IVehicleProcessorFactory {
   bool Supports(VehicleType vehicleType) => vehicleType == VehicleType.Van;
   IVehicleProcessor Create(String regNo) => new VanProcessor(regNo);
}

public class TruckProcessorFactory : IVehicleProcessorFactory {
   bool Supports(VehicleType vehicleType) => vehicleType == VehicleType.Truck;
   IVehicleProcessor Create(String regNo) => new TruckProcessor(regNo);
}

public VehicleProcessorProvider {
   private readonly IEnumerable<IVehicleProcessorFactory> _vehicleProcessorFactories;

   public VehicleProcessorProvider(IEnumerable<IVehicleProcessorFactory> vehicleProcessorFactories) {
        //The IoC container will automatically pass all the registered services for IVehicleProcessorFactory service type

        this._vehicleProcessorFactories = vehicleProcessorFactories;
   }

   public IVehicleProcessor GetProcessor(VehicleType type, String regNo) =>
       this._vehicleProcessorFactories
             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Supports(type))
             ?.Create(regNo) ??
             throw new Exception($"No processor factory found for {type}");
}

//Main
services.AddTransient<CarProcessorFactory, IVehicleProcessorFactory>();
services.AddTransient<VanProcessorFactory, IVehicleProcessorFactory>();
services.AddTransient<TruckProcessorFactory, IVehicleProcessorFactory>();
services.AddTransient<VehicleProcessorProvider>();

If now you need to support Bus as well, you need to:

Add Bus to the VehicleType enum
Create new BusProcessor and BusVehicleProcessor implementations
Register the processor factory in the IoC container (services.AddTransient<BusProcessorFactory, IVehicleProcessorFactory>())

If you don't want to touch any of the existing classes when adding a new vehicle, you can:

Change the Supports(VehicleType vehicleType) method to accept a type instead:

public interface IVehicleProcessorFactory {
     bool Supports(Type t);
     IVehicleProcessor Create(String regNo);
}

public class CarProcessorFactory : IVehicleProcessorFactory {
     bool Supports(Type t) => t == typeof(Car);
     IVehicleProcessor Create(String regNo) => new CarProcessor(regNo);
}


Adapt accordingly VehicleProcessorProvider.GetVehicleProcessor(VehicleType vehicleType, String regNo) to be GetVehicleProcessor(Type t, String regNo)

Use reflection to register the services in the IoC container



You can use the class' name instead of a static enum. This way you don't need to change your factory when adding new implementations of your interface.
public IVehicleProcessor GetVehicle(string typeName, string regNo) 
{
    var type = whateverAssembly.GetType(typeName);
    return (IVehicleProcessor) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}

You should also check if the type being found even implements the interface, e.g.:
if(type.GetInterface(nameof(IVehicleProcessor)) != null) ...


Ah, yes, stringly typed APIs, so that when you rename the class you have to hunt down all the places where its name is used, very maintainable.

@EtiennedeMartel eeeeh, no, as the name ideally would come from an external config-file. No code needs to change. Anyway, when OP wants dynamic types, you have no real other choice here.

The OP described in their question exactly how to do it without making it stringly typed.  They just need to implement their own proposal.

@Servy sure, but you need to add a new enum-value when adding a new processor. So two changes are needed, whereas you can achieve with a single. That's my entire point.

Also the OP said nothing about this coming from a config file.  All that they specified is that we have an enum, which could be coming from anywhere, not necessarily a config file or anything else not statically typed.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain  The difference between your proposal and the one the OP is asking for is yours has no static typing.  If you change any enum value you just have a bunch of magic strings everywhere, as opposed to the enum the OP has which will result in compiler errors if a value doesn't exist and allows for rename, etc. using bulit in refactors.
